# Хранение разных значений одного типа в одной записи MySql

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы. Одна таблица это товар, вторая категории товара. 
У товара может быть не больше 3-х категорий. 
Как лучше это хранить в базе данных? сделать связь между товарами и категориями один ко многим - один товар, 3 категории. и в таблице товара хранить id тех категорий к которым они относятся, но вопрос стоит как? создавать 3 столбца только для этого не очень как-то.
Ещё вариант создать промежуточную таблицу в которой будет хранится id товара | id категории.
Может есть какие-то ещё варианты?

Comment: Второй вариант, с отдельной таблицей товар-категория. И с поиском проще и задел на будущее, вдруг кто то захочет 4ю категорию добавить

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее универсальным будет решение с промежуточной таблицей для хранения связей между товарами и категориями. Для такого решения имеется специальное название - таблица соседства (Closure Table)

```
CREATE TABLE categories_products (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  catalog_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Можно проиндексировать внешние ключ для товаров и каталогов. Очень легко удалять и редактировать связи товаров и каталогов в промежуточной таблицы. Со временем, таблицу можно проиндексировать для ускорения запросов или ввести в нее дополнительное поле для сортировки категорий товара, если вдруг станет важным порядок следования категорий.